# Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value

Tags: c, strings, memory-management

Please review the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char *some_text = "THIS IS SOME ARBITRARY TEXT FOR TESTING THE STRLEN AND COPY FUNCTIONS";

    char *test = malloc(strlen(some_text) + 1);
    strncpy(test, some_text, strlen(some_text));
    strcat(test, "\0");

    printf("%s\n", test);
    if (test != NULL) free (test);
}
```

1. create a `char* some_text` with constant string;
2. create a `char*test` with and allocate memory the size of `some_text`
3. copy the content of `some_text` to `test`
4. concatenate the termination character to `test`
5. print out the `test`
6. free the `test` pointer

If I run this with `valgrind`, it says:

```
==31176== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==31176==    at 0x4008667: __GI_strlen (mc_replace_strmem.c:404)
==31176==    by 0x861DD4: puts (in /lib/libc-2.12.so)
==31176==    by 0x80484DF: main (strlen_and_copy.c:13)
```

The line mentioned in `valgrind` output strlen_and_copy.c:13 is below:

```
printf("%s\n", test);
```

Is it avoidable or should it be ignored? What is wrong with my code above?  Someone please explain.

Comment: Is that Valgrind's cryptic way of complaining that you didn't check whether `malloc()` returned `NULL`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some general remarks to your code:

1. You should store the string length as a variable rather than calling it multiple times.
2. If you do `strncpy(test, some_text, strlen(some_text) + 1)` you can get rid of the `strcat` as `strncpy` will padd the remainder with `\0` if `src` is less than `n` characters.
3. You don't need to test for `NULL` before `free`

   - a) because you'd get a segfault anyway before that line of code if it were `NULL`
   - b) because the standard guarantees that it is safe to call `free(NULL)`

Comment: Thaks @chrisWue, Actually why this output is coming in valgrind `==31176==    at 0x4008667: __GI_strlen (mc_replace_strmem.c:404)` ? Still it is availeble

Comment: Thaks @chrisWue, Ok. your 2nd point made it success.

Answer (score 6):

First string you pass to [strcat](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcat) is not null-terminated, which is incorrect (it takes two null-terminated byte strings). Actually it is null-terminated, but only because malloc returns pointer to zeroed memory on your system. Anyway, after call to strncpy you have a string with last byte uninitialized.

This code

```
strcat(test, "\0");
```

does nothing ("\0" and "" are equal).

To make it correct you can write

```
strcpy(test, some_text);
// without strcat
```

or

```
strncpy(test, some_text, strlen(some_text) + 1)
```

or

```
strncpy(test, some_text, strlen(some_text));
test[strlen(some_text)] = 0;
```

Comment: Good observation that `strcat()` cannot be used to add a NUL terminator to a string that doesn't already have one. Also a good observation that `test` is NUL terminated more by luck than by design. However, @ChrisWue's `strncpy(test, some_text, strlen(some_text) + 1)` is a better solution.